# How to divide the difference of the elements of one list by the elements of another list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wanted to divide the difference of elements in

```
A = [1,2,3,4]
```

by

```
B = [6,7,9].
```

I did:

```
for i in range(len(A)):
          A[i+1]-A[i]/B[i]
```

But, that is giving me an error that says: "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: What do you mean by "divide the difference of elements"? Provide the input and the expected output, at least.

Comment: Try to debug it: print the values of `i+1`, `i` in the loop and see which index you're trying to access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [16]: A = [1,2,3,4]

In [17]: B = [6,7,9]

In [18]: [(A[i+1]-A[i])/num for i,num in enumerate(B)]
Out[18]: [0.16666666666666666, 0.14285714285714285, 0.1111111111111111]
```

Or if you're dead set on a for-loop:

```
In [19]: answer = []

In [20]: for i in range(len(B)):
   ....:     answer.append((A[i+1]-A[i])/B[i])
   ....:     

In [21]: answer
Out[21]: [0.16666666666666666, 0.14285714285714285, 0.1111111111111111]
```

Comment: Thanks. What is I don't want to create a list? I want each individual element of the result?

Answer (score 3):

Because you are using `i+1` in your loop, when you reach the last iteration, `i == 3`, `A[4]` and `B[4]` are out of range:

What you are looking for is:

```
for i in range(len(A)-1):
    *something* (A[i+1]-A[i])/B[i]
```

which will iterate over `[0,1,2]`

Answer (score 2):

Another option is:

```
[(a-aa)/float(b) for a, aa, b in zip(A[1:], A[:-1], B)]
```

Note that your lists are lists of integers. Since you seem to be working on python 2.7, yo you either need cast to float (as I hacked in my solution) or you can use `from __future__ import division` to properly handle integer division.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it does. In your example, `range(len(A))` would go from 0 to 3, but `B[3]` doesn't exist. Nor does `A[3+1]`.

So the simple thing is to just change it to `range(len(B))`.

The next thing is that the calculation doesn't do what you want, because the division is done before the subtraction, so you need to change that into `(A[i+1] - A[i]) / B[i]`.

Finally, you need to store that somewhere. Here's it all together:

```
C = [0] * len(B)
for i in range(len(B)):
    C[i] = (A[i+1] - A[i]) / B[i]
```

To see how to do it all in a single line, look at @inspectorG4dget 's answer.

And finally, as @jorgeh points out: In this instance, you are doing integer division, which results in rounded-down integer results, all of which are 0 in your example.

Comment: Thanks. What should I do to get the floating numbers?

Comment: Okay, I figured that out. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
res = ((A[i+1] - A[i]) / (num*1.0) for i, num in enumerate(B)))
```

another way

```
from itertools import imap
res = imap(lambda x, y, z: (x-y)/(z*1.0), A[1:], A[:-1], B)
```